# Recaptcha v3 badge not showing (framework7)

Tags: recaptcha, html-framework-7

I'm trying to add recaptcha v3 to an app build using Framework 7. I have added the front end components and am getting a token back so I know that portion is working, however the recaptcha badge is not displaying on the page. When I inspect the page I can see the element but nothing is displayed. Any help would be appreciated .